# Reiterating through a list of matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, determinants

I am trying to go through a list of matrices (matList) to take the determinant of each matrix, and return a new list of all the determinant values.

So far, I have tried this:

```
matList

detList <- list()
for(i in matList){
  detList <- c(det(matList[i]))
  i + 1 
}

detList
```

But I get the error message: Error in UseMethod("determinant") : 
  no applicable method for 'determinant' applied to an object of class "list"

I know I can't take a determinant of a list but I called that function to each matrix, so I am not sure why I am getting this error message or how to fix it.

Comment: You aren't calling it on each matrix, you're calling it on a list of length one of a matrix. You want `matList[[i]]` not the single bracket version. Also, it still won't work because you would need `detList[i] <- ...`, and the manual increment of `i` will seriously break your loop; never modify the looping variable in a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is textbook example for using `lapply` (or `sapply` for that matter). Does

```
detList <- lapply(matList, det)
```

work?

It is functionally equivalent to

```
detList <- list()
for (i in matList){
  detList[i] <- det(matList[[i]])
}
```

which would be the proper loop as explained by @joran in the comments.

Comment: Glad I could help and welcome to stack overflow. Consider accepting it as the answer if you feel the question is answered.